# If date is ___ function with conditional formatting

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

Looking for help with the following function.

I need to highlight a cell, IF today's date is 2 months prior to, or in the month of X.

For example. If today's date is in february, march, or april, highlight cell B2.

I'm trying to write a custom formula in the conditional formatting option.
IF(A2=date(2/dd/yy),date(3/dd/yy),date(4/dd/yy))

Comment: It would help if you provided a sample sheet.  What value is in cell B2?  What value is in cell A2?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a date in cell A2, and you want to conditionally format A2 when it comes before today and after 3 months ago:

```
=(A2 < date(year(today()),month(today())+1,0))
*(date(year(A2),month(A2)-3,0) < today())
```